# dynamically change the filter expression

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of records. This array will display different records based on the user's permissions.

Thus I have to use a different filter based upon the user. How do i create such an expression which takes a variable function based on the user's permission -

```
<div ng-repeat="r in records | filter:{isVisible:true}"
```

The above has a filter expression {isVisible:true}. I want to dynamically assign a different filter expression based on the user. So user2 will have {isCommon: 'M2'}.

Comment: So if I change the JavaScript, can I see records I'm not supposed to see?  In other words, might there be some serious security issues with this approach?

Comment: +1 for that Mark. I will surely make that change in live apps. However this is for prototype.

Comment: I know its an old post, but.. Whatever you send to the client can be seen, so relying on filters to hide sensitive data is unwise.

Comment: Heads-up is always useful but this could be an admin page that lists specific users...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filter expressions can be variables too:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterExpr">{{item.name}}</li>
```

Where the expression is defined on the scope:

```js
$scope.filterExpr = { tester: true };
```

Here's a Plunker that demonstrates this more completely: http://plnkr.co/edit/Au8KFg?p=preview

PS: Do pay heed to @MarkRajcok's comment to your post as it is **very** important to note.

Comment: +1 for the answer Josh. Also why doesnt it work if $scope.filterEcp = "{tester: true}", ie if the filter expression is a string instead of an object?

Comment: @murtaza52 When a string expression is used, $filter will only return substring matches. If you do `filter:'one'` or `$scope.filterExp = 'one'` it will stringify the object from the array and see if "one" is contained within it. You could emulate my answer with `$scope.filterExp = 'true'`, but it's not evaluating a Boolean expression; it's just matching on the substring.

Answer (score 2):

2Terry Drozdowski - absolutely right: filter doesn't work on Boolean for recent version(1.1.7). Thank you for pointing this out - you have to use quotes:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in records | filter:{isVisible:'true'}"
```