# Applying dynamic filters in Angularjs templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building a table based on user defined column definitions as in this:

http://jsfiddle.net/waylon999/2RvmW/1/

You'll notice I have a filter field in columns that I haven't been able to apply.  I've tried:

```
{{ getItem(data, col.keyword) | col.filter }}
```

which in chrome gives the following error:
Unknown provider: col.filterFilterProvider <- col.filterFilter

I've also tried modifying the getItem method to build out the filter string, but it just ends up rendering the

```
| uppercase
```

as text, appended to the text. So I get output like:

Foo | uppercase

Is there a way that I can apply this filter with how I'm building the tables?

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296241/dynamically-change-the-filter-expression

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
<tr ng-repeat='data in myData'>
   <td ng-repeat='col in columns'> {{data[col.keyword] | uppercase}}</td>
</tr>
```

Have a nice develop day !

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RvmW/5/)

Comment: I think the OP's question was basically how to dynamically define which filter is used in a template rather than hardcode it. The linked question in the comment above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296241/dynamically-change-the-filter-expression) answers it. Filter expressions can be vars too: "item in items | filter:filterExpr"