# AngularJS determine filter in controller

Tags: angularjs

How would I go about setting the filter property on an ng-repeat dynamically?

Here is my template...

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div ng-repeat="article in articles | activeFilter">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ article.title }}</h3>
        <h4 class="list-group-item-text">{{ article.author }}</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">"{{ article.blurb }}"</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Where "activeFilter" is a property I want to set via the controller...

...

```
$scope.activeFilter = 'someFilterType'
```

...

And the filter looks like this...

```
.filter('someFilterType', function () {
      return function (items) {
        var rv = [];
        for (var p in items) {
          if (items[p].myFilterProp === false)
          rv.push(items[p]);
        }
        return rv;
      }
    })
```

I would think I could dynamically change the ng-repeat's filter in this way, but it doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why aren't you calling to the filter directly ?

Comment: It's because your scope variable is a string. To do what you want you may have to ditch the custom filter module, and use a controller function as a filter.

Comment: As in, `ng-repeat="e in array" | myCustomFunction()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically change the filter expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296241/dynamically-change-the-filter-expression)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:activeFilter[filter]"
```

Controller:

```
$scope.filter = "name1";

$scope.activeFilter = {
    name1: $scope.someFilterFunction,
    name2: $scope.someOtherFilter,
    name3: $scope.andAnother
};

$scope.someFilterFunction = function() {
    var rv = [];
    for (var p in items) {
        if (items[p].myFilterProp === false)
            rv.push(items[p]);
        }
    return rv;
};
```

Comment: Binding the function in this way will certainly do the trick, but it really cuts down on the flexibility of what I was trying to do.

Comment: I edited it, how about something like that? Then you can just change the value of filter to 1 or 2 and have different filters defined.

Comment: My point was to define the activeFilter according to a button clicked in the view, where the view's controller would reach out to a service and update the parameter. Any controllers observing that service would then update their views accordingly.

Comment: This is quite nifty, but not that extensible.