# Use AND & OR operations in Angular Filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am developing a Grid which consist of 7 columns using ng-table. Each columns has multiple values. I need to apply Filter with combination of multiple values with Combination of Columns. 
Example:

Column 1 - Value 11 , value 12, value 13

Column 2 - Value 21 , Value 22, Value 23

Column 3 - Value 31 , Value 32, Value 33

I need to apply the following filter expression.

( (Column1=Value11 || Column1=Value12 || Column1=Value13) &&  (Column2=Value21 || Column2=Value22 || Column2=Value23) &&  (Column3=Value31 || Column3=Value32 || Column3=Value33)
)

Each selection of Values are existing in Check boxes. On selection of each check box I  need to format the above mentioned filter expression and Apply it.
Is this possible in Angular Filter? .  Please help it.

Answer (score -1):

Start off by making the filter an expression in js like this post:

[dynamically change the filter expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296241/dynamically-change-the-filter-expression)

To update the filter with the selections, you can add an ng-click event or make an event listener using something like $watch.

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/responding-to-scope-changes.html

In that link, the `$scope.$watch("name"` part means that `name` is a variable in your current scope, declared in your controller like `$scope.name = expression`.